# How to replace a string in text without truncating extra text, .seek() issue?

Tags: python, text

I am using the following code to find and replace characters in a text

```
for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.txt')):
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        with open(file, 'r+', encoding = 'windows-1250') as f:
            content = f.read()
            f.seek(0)
            f.truncate()
            f.write(content.replace('Ă', '’'))
```

however extra text is being truncated in the file. Is this because of using .seek()? How can I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: I may not be understanding what you're trying to do, but this code seems to work. What extra text is being truncated?

Comment: I just ran it again so I could paste an example, but this time it worked fine...very odd. It was adding extra parts of sentences to the end of the text, I think taken from the point of the string I'd replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra text is being truncated because you used a `seek` value of `0`. Since
the current place in the file is the default `size` parameter for `truncate`,
it truncates everything.

More [here.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_truncate.htm)

Comment: OK, that makes sense, thank you. But I can't work out how to get around it? Do I essentially want to tell it to start seeking at 0 but then end at the end of the document?

Comment: It's a little hard to tell when one doesn't know what the file looks like, but from what I could gleam you're trying to replace one char with another, file-wide right?

Comment: Yes that's right. I just ran the code again to get some examples to show and it worked fine...now I'm even more confused!

Comment: Interesting! Looking at the code again I guess I would expect that to work as content is saved before the truncate. Maybe the "error" was with how you are viewing the results?

Comment: It must have been, although not sure how that came about. Thank you for your help anyway and now I understand .seek and .truncate better.